# How do I add ImageMap control and hotspots to my web page filled by image from database

Tags: c#, webforms

Im displaying **jpg** or **gif** images from **sql** using **BinaryWrite** method. Image is loaded as expected. I want to add hotspots on that image. I cannot point any **ImageUrl** to the **ImageMap**, so I think main problem lies there.

I added **ImageMap** control and associated hotspots on **Page_Load** in code behind. No success.

I put the control before `Response.End()`, since thereafter no more code is executed.

No hotspot is observed on the image. Is there any way to accomplish this as I can not embed the images as open files in the server.

Here is last part of my code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // After db connection and filling the data
    try
    {
        objAdapter.Fill(objTable);

        objRow = objTable.Rows[0];
        byte[] objData;
        objData = (byte[])objRow["Resim"];
        string name = (string)objRow["ResimAd"];
        char[] sep = { '.' };
        string[] nname;
        nname = name.Split(sep);
        int il = nname.Length;

        if (nname[il - 1] == "pdf" || nname[il - 1] == "PDF")
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";      
        }
        else if (nname[il - 1] == "xls" || nname[il - 1] == "XLS" || nname[il - 1] == "xlsx" || nname[il - 1] == "XLSX" || nname[il - 1] == "XLSB"
            || nname[il - 1] == "xlsb" || nname[il - 1] == "XLSM" || nname[il - 1] == "xlsm" || nname[il - 1] == "CSV" || nname[il - 1] == "csv")
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";      // excel dosya
        }
        else if (nname[il - 1] == "doc" || nname[il - 1] == "docx" || nname[il - 1] == "rtf")
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";      
        }
        else
        {
            Response.ContentType = "image";          
        }

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + name + "\"");  
        Response.BinaryWrite(objData);
        Response.Flush();

        // Here I add ImageMap :
        ImageMap ImageMap1 = new ImageMap
        {
            HotSpotMode = HotSpotMode.Navigate,
        };
        Page.Controls.Add(ImageMap1);
        RectangleHotSpot hs1 = new RectangleHotSpot
        {
            Left = 0,
            Right = 500,
            Top = 0,
            Bottom = 500,
            AlternateText = "XXXXXXX",
            NavigateUrl = "~/Default.aspx"
        };
        ImageMap1.HotSpots.Add(hs1);
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         labelError.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: ImageMap is an HTML concept.  It should be created in the page that consumes/displays the image, not on the "page" that creates the image.

Comment: So you mean ImageMap control should be added at the aspx side. I've already done this. No difference. Besides, I must add the hotspots at the code side with their coordinates recorded.

Comment: Thanks to those who showed interest. I solved the issue myself.

Comment: You should post your solution in the answer box below so it may benefit others.

Answer (score 0):

I put the ImageMap in a FormView. Tied the binary imagedata to it,  and pointed the ImageUrl to the DataItem. So, the ImageMap is defined, with as many hotspots as I want addable. Works perfect.